# How to concatenate Thymeleaf message with jquery variable

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

In my messages I have:

```
resetPassword.sending.email=Sending email
resetPassword.sending.sms=Sending sms
```

I want to use it in the HTML and JQuery but I am unable to pass the variable to form the message. I will have multiple messaging methods so I can't just use if else statement, it has to be dynamic.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

$("#sendButton").click(function(e) {
    sedingMethod = $(this).data('method'); // can be 'sms' or 'email'
    $("#sendingMessage").text([[#{resetPassword.sending.[sedingMethod]}]]);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Thyemelaf is processed at the server and jQuery runs on client. One possible way is to get all the relevant messages into the Javascript and then use it in jQuery. Something like:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
 var resetPasswordSendingEmail = /*[[#{resetPassword.sending.email}]]*/'';
 var resetPasswordSendingSms = /*[[#{resetPassword.sending.sms}]]*/'';
 var messageMap = { 'email' : resetPasswordSendingEmail, 'sms': resetPasswordSendingSms };
</script>
```

Then in the JS you can pick your variable without the need of `if..else` as shown below:

```
var message = messageMap[sedingMethod];
```

Answer (score 0):

See here:

https://www.concretepage.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-javascript-inline-example-with-variable

So I believe this would work:

```
$("#sedingMessage").text([[${resetPassword.sending.sendingMethod}]]);
```

Comment: I tried this (replacing $ with # for the messages), but sendingMethod is not passed for it's value, but it's looking for message with the key `resetPassword.sending.sendingMethod`